# Как обрезать часть ссылки?

Tags: jquery

Есть например у меня ссылка!

```
/catalog/fm_modulyatory/index.php?action=ADD2BASKET&amp;id=26045&amp;quantity=1
```

Задача такая что нужно удалить `quantity=1` или просто удалить то что находиться после  знака `=`. То есть воспользовались какой то функцией и у нас получилась такая ссылка `/catalog/fm_modulyatory/index.php?action=ADD2BASKET&amp;id=26045&amp;quantity=`

Поначалу пробывал `split()` но не то! Если ли какая либо функция которая способна это делать, или как можно это реализовать. Структура ссылки будет такой всегда.

> Можно конечно удалять одно значение ссылки но вдруг там будет
>   двухзначное число или трехзначное число!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let str = '/fm_modulyatory/index.php?action=ADD2BASKET&amp;id=26045&amp;quantity=1';

console.log(str.replace(/quantity=[0-9]+/, '')); // первый вариант
console.log(str.replace(/(quantity=)[0-9]+/, '$1')); // второй
```